# angularjs - $locationChangeStart - data set on rootScope isn't available in my controller

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I have an app where certain routes are restricted if the user is not logged in. This is my run function:

```
function run($rootScope, $location, UserService) {
    var homeRoute = '/';

    $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
        var isPageRestricted = $.inArray($location.path(), [homeRoute, '']) === -1;

        if (!isPageRestricted) {
            return;
        }

        UserService
            .verifyUserToken()
            .then(function(data) {
                var userData;

                if (data.valid) {
                    $rootScope.userData = $rootScope.userData || UserService.getUserTokenAndData();
                } else {
                    $rootScope.userData = null;
                    $location.path(homeRoute);
                }
            })
            .catch(function() {
                $rootScope.userData = null;
                $location.path(homeRoute);
            });
    });
}
```

As you can see, when a user enters a restricted route, I send a request to the server to verify its token. If the token is valid, I store the user's data to `$rootScope.userData`. Then, in one of my restricted views I get that `$rootScope.userData` is `null` in the beginning, and non-null after page is refreshed. I presume it is because of the asynchronous nature of the operation. What is the best way to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: trying to use `$rootScope` for storing "global" variables is a fundamental misunderstanding of how `$rootScope` works.  While this can *sometimes* work, it's not the purpose `$rootScope` is meant to serve.

Comment: I don't understand what you suggest.

Comment: The $locationChangeStart event is finished way before the promise is resolved.  You have to call event.preventDefault() and then redirect yourself once the promise is resolved